# Is there a better way to find children and parents of an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a gem to export a small portion of related ActiveRecord objects.

Here's how I'm currently finding parents & children.

```
# belongs_to, based on column names with an _id suffix
def belongs_to_relations(ar_instance)
    columns = ar_instance.class.column_names
    parents = columns.map{ |c| c if c =~ /_id/ }.reject{ |c| c.nil? }
    parents.map!{ |parents| parents.gsub('_id', '') }
end

# has_many, based on existence of a xxx_id column in other tables
def has_many_relations(ar_instance)
    column_name = "#{ar_instance.class.name.underscore}_id"
    descendents = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
    descendents.reject!{ |table| false unless table.classify.constantize rescue true }
    descendents.reject!{ |table| true unless table.classify.constantize.column_names.include?(column_name) }
end
```

Is there a better way to find these relationships? This works *ok*, but distant relationships, like :through, I have to specify manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class.reflections`. It returns information about a model's relationships.

Imagine you have this simple set up:

```
# user.rb
belongs_to :user_type
has_many :user_logs
```

If you call `User.reflections` you will get a hash similar to the following:

```
{
  :user_type => <Reflection @macro=:belongs_to, etc. ...>,
  :user_logs => <Reflection @macro=:has_many, etc. ...>
}
```

The reflection is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection` or `ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection`. It contains information about which model it references, what the options are (like `dependent => :destroy`), what type of association it is (the `@macro` in my example), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if that's what you're looking for but ActiveRecord has helpers to do this. 
In your models:

```
#school.rb
has_many :classrooms

#classroom.rb
belongs_to :school
```

You can now use pretty much anywhere:

```
school = random_classroom.school
classrooms = school.classrooms
```

For a `has_many :through` relationship:

```
# school.rb
  has_many :students,
           :through => :classrooms
```